# midje does not stub functions provided with hashmaps

Tags: clojure, stub, midje

Consider the following code

```
(use 'midje.sweet)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
(defn x2 [x] (* x x))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
(def fs {:x2 x2})                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
(fact                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  (x2 1) => "one"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  ((:x2 fs) 1) => "one"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  (against-background                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    (#'tweetfetcher.core-test/x2 1) => "one"))
```

which outputs

```
FAIL at (core_test.clj:177)
    Expected: "one"
      Actual: 1
FAILURE: 1 check failed.  (But 32 succeeded.)
```

The first check is stubbed while the second use `x2` as provided by the hashmap `fs`.

Considering I rule out referencing, why is  `(:x2 fs)` not stubbed ?

Thanks for insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not surprised it works this way. In `(x2 1)`, it is known compile-time that `x2` is the function defined as `(defn x2 [x] (* x x))`.

In `((:x2 fs) 1)`, we know, compile-time, that `fs` is `{:x2 x2}`, but we don't yet know the result of `(:x2 fs)`. By that I mean the expression `(:x2 fs)` is not evaluated during `fact` expansion. It probably sees that `(:x2 fs)` is not a var that resolves to a function and therefore does nothing to associate it with our stub (inside `against-background`).